# Python - Repeat a biased coin flip experiment

Tags: python, function, for-loop, simulation, coin-flipping

I'm trying to write a function that simulates X number of biased coin flip experiments (H=0.6, T=0.4), which consists of N coin flips, to answer the question "What is the expected value of the number of groups after N coin flips." Group, by definition, is the maximal sequences of the same values in consecutive order.

For example: `['H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H']` has 3 groups and `['T', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H']` has 4 groups.

```
# Libraries
import random
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import chain

# Function for biased coin
def flip(p):
    return 'H' if random.random() < p else 'T'

# Number of coin flips
N = 10
flips = [flip(0.6) for i in range(N)]
print (len(list(groupby(flips))))

# Function to simulate X iterations of N coin flips
def simulate(X, N):
    Outcome = [] # Empty list to store each experiment's result
    # X Number of coin simulations
    for i in range(X):
        # Coin simulation of N flips
        flips = [flip(0.6) for j in range(N)]
        # Append experiment's result into Outcome list
        Outcome.append(len(list(groupby(flips))))
    # Expected Value of the number of groups
    sum(Outcome)/X
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? I got the following error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'`

Comment: What does “doesn’t work” mean? `Outcome/X` (dividing a list by an integer – not a thing) is probably part of it, but anything else?

Comment: It works for me! What are you expecting and what are you getting that makes you feel this doesn't work!

Comment: i got the following error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'`

Comment: I figured out out happened: `Outcome` was defined before and I totally forgot about it. >.>

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing a list by a number.
And you need to use return in your function.

```
def simulate(X, N):

    Outcome = [] # Empty list to store each experiment's result
    # X Number of coin simulations
    for i in range(X):
        # Coin simulation of N flips
        flips = [flip(0.6) for j in range(N)]
        # Append experiment's result into Outcome list
        Outcome.append(len(list(groupby(flips))))
    X = float(X)
    # Expected Value of the number of groups
    return sum(Outcome)/X
```

Comment: The denominator is wrong

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to take the average of the outcomes, so instead of storing them in a list, you want to add them up and divide by the number of trials.

```
def simulate(x, n):
    outcome = 0.0
    for i in range(x):
        flips = [flip(0.6) for j in range(n)]
        outcome += len(list(groupby(flips)))
    return outcome / x
```

Comment: The denominator is wrong

Comment: It's the average of `x` samples.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Libraries
import random
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import chain

# Function for biased coin
def flip(p):
    return 'H' if random.random() < p else 'T'

# Number of coin flips
N = 10
flips = [flip(0.6) for i in range(N)]
print (len(list(groupby(flips))))

# Function to simulate X iterations of N coin flips
def simulate(X, N):
    Outcome = []
    for i in range(X):
        flips = [flip(0.6) for j in range(N)]
        Outcome.append(len(list(groupby(flips))))
    print(sum(Outcome)/(X))
```